# Why is my table column not aligning left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap, and am trying to get my "title" column in a table to align left, but it is not working. Can anybody suggest what might I be missing here?

```css
table td {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date </th>
        <th>Time (IST)</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Speaker</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Dec 17</td>
        <td>13:00 pm to 14:00 pm</td>
        <td>intro</td>
        <td>me</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dec 17</td>
        <td>14:00 pm to 16:00 pm</td>
        <td>main topic</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Ultimately, I may need some column left and some right aligned.
Here is the example URL: http://www.msbiria.org/ultrafest/schedule.php

[image]

Comment: I can see everything left-aligned in the link you provide. Maybe what you actually want is for the columns in the different tables to be aligned with each other?

Comment: @abl i have added a screenshot above, to show you the area where you may be seeing the alignment issue. I would want all columns to be at same place across all the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clean and general way to make this happen. You have two independent tables and there is no reason why the column widths in one of them should bear any relation to the column widths in the other.

In this particular case, given that you know the nature of the content that will go into the tables (i.e. first a date, which doesn't require much space, then the time, then the title which needs more space, then the speaker) I suggest to set the column widths yourself.

1. Add a class `schedule-table` to the affected tables.
2. Add a `colgroup` to every table:

```html
<table class="table schedule-table">
    <colgroup>
        <col></col>
        <col></col>
        <col></col>
        <col></col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
    ...
```

3. Set the (relative) column widths through CSS:

```css
.schedule-table colgroup col:nth-of-type(1){
    width: 10%;
}
.schedule-table colgroup col:nth-of-type(2){
    width: 30%;
}
.schedule-table colgroup col:nth-of-type(3){
    width: 40%;
}
.schedule-table colgroup col:nth-of-type(4){
    width: 20%;
}
```

4. Set the CSS of the cells so that the text wraps around when it doesn't fit in the cell.

```css
.schedule-table td {
    white-space:normal !important;
}
```

Here's **[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/p1bk363h/)**

Answer (score 0):

The table class in bootstrap is 100% width.
 .table {width:100%}

Try 
.table {width:auto}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option if you don't know the width of the data. It uses one table and bolds the rows that are headers so it looks the exact same.

```css
.schedule-table h4 { margin: 0px }
.bold { font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table schedule-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="bg-info">
                    <h4>December 17, 2014 (Wednesday)</h4>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bold">
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Time (IST)</td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Speaker</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dec 17</td>
                <td>13:00 pm to 14:00 pm</td>
                <td>intro</td>
                <td>me</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dec 17</td>
                <td>14:00 pm to 16:00 pm</td>
                <td>main topic</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="bg-info">
                    <h4>December 17, 2014 (Wednesday)</h4>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bold">
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Time (IST)</td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Speaker</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dec 17</td>
                <td>13:00 pm to 14:00 pm</td>
                <td>intro</td>
                <td>me</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dec 17</td>
                <td>14:00 pm to 16:00 pm</td>
                <td>main topic</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```